# Scan for Android Beacon every X minutes

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon, eddystone

I want to make an app (or service) that always looks for beacons every minute. If it finds one, it shall start an intentService and upload coordinates to my server.

I have looked at examples in the [altbeacon documentation](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/index.html) and they are indeed working. However, I am not able to tweak it the way I want.

The best example I found was [how to start an app in the background](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html#Starting-an-App-in-the-Background). Here I can set the interval time, scan time, and it is doing what it should - except it only announces new beacons (didEnterRegion method).

There is also an example that continuously scans for beacons ([Getting Ranging Updates from Nearby Beacons With Telemetry](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/eddystone-how-to.html)), but I have not been able to control the interval and scan time (even though it says it is configurable). Also, I must make sure that this will always run, and never goes into some kind of sleepmode.

Lastly, I have tried to mix all of this into my own service using various timer approaches, but I was told by a distant co-worker that the altbeacon library makes a service by itself, and I should not have to.

Does anyone have any tips on how to do this?

**Edit**

I have used davidgyoung's approach, since the example seems to be pretty much out of the box for me. I will need a few days to test, and get back with an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this with the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) is quite straightforward, and you can use the [reference app](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference) as a starting point.

It is true that you do not need to make your own service, as the library has one of its own.  Using the reference app as-is, it starts up automatically on the background and scans for beacons at boot, and will restart itself within five minutes using an AlarmManager even if you kill the app.

Using this approach, simply start ranging in the Application class and process your results in a callback method in that class.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use [Estimote API](http://developer.estimote.com/android/tutorial/part-2-background-monitoring/) for this. 
Manually you can create service, create instance of `BeaconManager` if it `== null` on service or your command started. Add `setMonitoringListener` and now you can send results from `onEnteredRegion`.

Comment: I will take a look. I can use this even if my Beacon is not an Estimote?

Comment: @mathkid91 most of Beacons have the same data structure. So be free to test it.